# Getting shared preferences data of another class

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, sharedpreferences

Im trying to make a favorites list. I have this class called Animal and another called Favorites. The favorites arraylist is created in the class Favorites. I can access the favorites arraylist from Animal with

```
public static Favorites addfavorite = new Favorites();
```

and add items to the favorits list.

As the items that are added from the Animal class to the favorites list i need this arraylist to be saved. I tried to do this with SharedPreferences. It almost works. After adding items and completely closing and reopening the app i get the following problem.

**Problem:**

If i open the app and go to the Animal class, without opening the Favorites class first and seeing the previously added items (So the `OnCreate()` method for Favorites hasn't been called yet), and if i add or dont add a new item to favorites list (it doesn't matter) while I'm in Animal class, when i open the 'Favorites' class the previously added items are deleted and replaced by the newly added ones if new items are added, if not the list becomes empty. (I dont want this i need to have both the old and new items) But if i first open the Favorites class and see the previously added items(thus having the 'OnCreate()' method be called for 'Favorites') and then go to the Animal class and add new items both the new and old items are listed in 'Favorites'. (This is what I'm trying to achieve)

How do i fix this problem?

EDIT: Some code from Animal

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putStringSet(PREFS_NAME, 
                 new HashSet<String>(addfavorite.getFavorites()));
    editor.commit();
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    favoritesanimal = new ArrayList<String>(prefs.getStringSet(PREFS_NAME,
            new HashSet<String>()));

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList(PREFS_NAME, addfavorite.getFavorites());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(PREFS_NAME)) {
        favoritesanimal = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(PREFS_NAME);

    }
}
```

favoritesanimal is an arbitrary arraylist i created. It isnt related to the Favorite class or the favoriteslist Its actually useless. So the onPause() and onResume methodes do nothing at the moment.

And here is code from Favorites (notice i am using the same sharedpreferences attributes in both classes)

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    favorites = new ArrayList<String>(prefs.getStringSet(PREFS_NAME,
            new HashSet<String>()));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


                        //As you can see i added SharedPreferences to OnCreate
                       //more code..
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putStringSet(PREFS_NAME, new HashSet<String>(favorites));
    editor.commit();
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    favorites = new ArrayList<String>(prefs.getStringSet(PREFS_NAME,
            new HashSet<String>()));

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList(PREFS_NAME, favorites);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(PREFS_NAME)) {
        favorites = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(PREFS_NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: post some code from onCreate() method here...

Comment: I added some relevant code

Comment: What is the `addfavorite` variable that you use in `onPause` of the `Animal`?

Comment: 'addfavorite.getFavorites()' allows me to access my main favorites arraylist that i created in the 'Favorites' class

Answer (score 0):

I think that, when you use `addfavorite.getFavorites()`, this method returns empty list. And when you goes to Favorites class, `onPause()` method in Animals class is called and rewrote your preferences.

Comment: Any ideas on how i can fix it?

Comment: I think something like: when you try to save favorites - first get old favorites form preferences, add new favorites and then save. Or in `getFavorites()` method get shared preferences if arraylist wasn't initialized and return them.